# How Would You Redirect a Mobile Webpage based on Carrier?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

I'm having some difficulty Googling the answer for this.

Basically I have a page, then I want to redirect them based on Carrier (for example, Sprint, Verizon, Tmobile, etc).   So if they are Verizon, they get sent to a Verizon specific-page.

The only information I would have is the IP, hostname, etc.  I wouldn't be asking for any information such as their phone number.

By the looks of it, would this be done with hostname?   Is there a list available of all mobile carrier hostnames?

Comment: Use the phone.carrier.name enum :-)

Comment: You want to detect persons carrier when they visit your mobile site, via browser?

Comment: Yes I want to detect carrier when they visit my webpage.  I can determine the browser and stuff easily (whether mobile or not).  But I then want to redirect based on the carrier (verizon, sprint, etc). I have a feeling this is done with the hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Servers have hostnames, clients usually do not. Do you know yours?

The only thing you can do is a reverse IP lookup. This could give the name of ISP that is hosting the client IP, from where the request is comming. See this: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

The only limitation is that user has to be on carriers network. So most non-carrier wifi networks will not get you correct info.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).  Create a list of carriers then and compare also make sure to have a default case as there maybe cases where the carrier name has changed or you didn't add something to your list.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String name = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: ideally i would like to do this all on my server, without a 3rd party service (except maxmind which i do have installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handset Detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com) with the [Javascript mobile detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com/resources) method.

If you setup a site profile with no detection rules you can write 
custom javascript to access HandsetDetection.isp then redirect them
where ever you like.

Hope that helps. (Disclaimer: I work there).